# Is loop in C guaranteed to be executed in order?

Tags: c, loops, optimization

Is 'for' loop in ANSI-C guaranteed to be executed in order, or can it be optimized by compiler using out-of-order execution?
If so, which compilers do that? In which optimization level? How can this optimization be prevented?

Comment: theoretically a loop could be executed out of order if the code was "magically" parallelized, and each thread ran at different speeds. I'd had to think just how ugly it would be debug such a situation...

Comment: Optimizations are not allowed to change the sequential behavior of a correct program. So no, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler has the right to execute statements out of order if it is able to determine it does not change the observable behavior of the program. Use `volatile` objects if you want to execute statements strictly according to the rules of C abstract machine.

Comment: As far as I know volatile is a hint for the compiler, that a value might change outside the code's responsibility (e.g. by a parallel process or by hardware) and thus disables optimizations which could be problematic.

So I assume it also means, that the order of reads and writes must be preserved (which makes sense for special function registers). Is that the case?


Maybe you know of a compiler (and possibly an example) using out-of-order optimization?

Comment: @theldoria C imposes requirements on expression involving volatile-qualified objects: *(C99, 6.7.3p6) "An object that has volatile-qualified [...]. Therefore any expression referring to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, as described in 5.1.2.3."* and *(C99, 5.1.2.3p8) "EXAMPLE 1 An implementation might define a one-to-one correspondence between abstract and actual semantics: at every sequence point, the values of the actual objects would agree with those specified by the abstract semantics. The keyword volatile would then be redundant."*

Comment: @theldoria: writes and reads to `volatile` qualified objects are considered to be part of the observable behaviour of the program, so therefore they must be done in program order with respect to other observable behaviour.